# Django Advanced Search Functionally

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, advanced-search

Ive been searching google for hours but haven't been able to find anything. Im rather new to Django and was wondering how to accomplish the following

Im looking to implement a search on a page to filter records that are returned by a query Similar to how eBay do. (see link down left hand side)

[Link to eBay to show desired search functionality](http://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/i.html?_trksid=p2050601.m570.l1313.TR12.TRC2.A0.H0.Xmk5%20golf%20gti&_nkw=mk5%20golf%20gti&_sacat=0&_from=R40)

Could some one me in the right direction or tell me what need to look into to implement such a feature.

Comment: You have a form with the filters, you submit the form and all the filters are sent to the same page as GET parameters. You parse and query using the parameters and send back the result. What's the trouble here?

Answer (score 0):

use `get_search_results`(new in django 1.6)

```
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'age')
    search_fields = ('name',)

    def get_search_results(self, request, queryset, search_term):
        queryset, use_distinct = super(PersonAdmin, self).get_search_results(request, queryset, search_term)
        try:
            search_term_as_int = int(search_term)
            queryset |= self.model.objects.filter(age=search_term_as_int)
        except:
            pass
        return queryset, use_distinct
```

`search_term` is what you input, and `query_set` is the result,you need to change query_set